# i am unable to initilize vector with initilize elements

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vector, apple-m1

I am unable to initialize the vector with initial elements.

I am receiving this error:

> no instance of constructor "std::__1::vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::vector
> [with _Tp=int, _Allocator=std::__1::allocator]" matches the
> argument list

[image: snapshot of my code and error]

I am using VS Code on a MacBook Air M1.

Comment: This form of initialization was added in C++11. You must be using a very old compiler.

Comment: You are using C++ 98. Since you are using a modern notebook, I suggest you verity your compiler installation.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks *@BoP*.
I have just changed my settings to c++14 and it worked [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euqTZ.png).